# Why I get the error 'Call to undefined function delete_cookie ()' on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think the code that I run is correct, but a moment in the run even appear error 'Call to undefined function delete_cookie ()'

Please for correction :)

in Controller Product_Ref.php

```
public function index()
    {
    $ref = $this->input->get('id');
    $getIdOrder = $this->product_model->getIdOrder($ref);
    if ($getIdOrder) {
      $this->load->helper('cookie');
      $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'refProductcookie',
        'value'  => $ref,
        'expire' => '43200'
      );
      $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
      echo get_cookie('refProductcookie').'<br>';
    }else {
      echo "Sorry this product has not been registered yet";
      delete_cookie('refProductcookie');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load helper `cookie` for both of your `if-else`-cases:

```
// load BEFORE `if`
$this->load->helper('cookie');
if ($getIdOrder) {
  $cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'refProductcookie',
    'value'  => $ref,
    'expire' => '43200'
  );
  $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
  echo get_cookie('refProductcookie').'<br>';
}else {
  echo "Sorry this product has not been registered yet";
  delete_cookie('refProductcookie');
}
```

Comment: Thx, Very Good........It's Work :),.........
I think the position will not affect

Answer (score 1):

problem is in else statement didnt load cookie helper, add this line in else statement or better top of if `$this->load->helper('cookie');`

Comment: You mean `top`?

Comment: before if statement.